# Finding longest word error?

Tags: python, string, list, split, cpu-word

I'm trying to find the longest word in Python but I'm getting the wrong result. The code below was done in interactive mode. I should've received 'merchandise' (10 characters) as the longest word/string but I got 'welcome' (7 characters) instead.

```
 str = 'welcome to the merchandise store' #string of words
 longest = []                             #empty list
 longest = str.split()                    #put strings into list
 max(longest)                             #find the longest string
 'welcome'                                #Should've been 'merchandise?'
```

Answer (score 5):

It's sorting the strings alphabetically not by length, what you need is:

```
max(longest, key=len)
```

Let me clarify a little bit further. In Python the default comparison for strings is alphabetical. This means "aa" will be less than "abc" for all intents and purposes (cmp in python2 and < in python2/3). If you call max on the list without a key then it will compare using the default comparison. If you put in a key function then it will compare the key instead of the value. Another options (python2 only) is the cmp argument to max, which takes a function like [cmp](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#cmp). I don't suggest this method because it's going to end up being something like `cmp=lambda x,y: len(x)-len(y)` which seems much less readable then just `key=len` and isn't supported in python3.

If you have any more questions about using key, I'd suggest reading [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-mutable) specifically note (7) which covers cmp and key for list.sort which uses them in the same manner.

Comment: Is there another way without using the Lambda?

Comment: Oh, right, yeah. Now that I think of it, the lamba is superfluous since len is a function, not a method.

Comment: @VincentLuc Is there a reason, why you do not want the `key=len`? If you omitted this part, you would just get just be your first attempt that failed... Or do you look for some kind of one-argument-funtion?

Comment: I take that back, the key=len is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can also so do this:

```
str = 'welcome to the merchandise store'
sorted(str.split(), key=len)[-1]
```

Split it, sort them by length, then take the longest (last one).

Comment: Dude, that's an order O(n log(n)) operation, whereas max(...) is an order O(n) operation.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `str.split()` to `str.split(" ")`

Then,

```
max = []
for x in str.split(" "):
    if len(x) > len(max[0]):
        max = []
        max.append(x)
    elif len(x) == len(max[0]):
        max.append(x)
```

Answer (score -1):

This is one way to do it without the `lambda` or `key=len` just using a `for loop` and `list comprehension`:

```
str = 'welcome to the merchandise store' 
longest = []                             
longest = str.split()
lst = []
for i in longest:
    x = len(i)
    lst.append(x)
y = [a for a in longest if max(lst)== len(a)]
print y[0]
```

Output:

```
merchandise
```

*This is in Python 2, in Python 3* `print (y[0])`